# Why is it ok to take square root of $|z|^2$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

Why is it ok to take square root of $|z|^2$, $z=a+ib \in \mathbb{C}$?

Is it because

$$|z|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

$$ \implies |z|^2=a^2+b^2 \in \mathbb{R}$$

and the square root of a positive real number is surely defined
?

As a beginner in complex analysis I was expecting for square root to be defined separately for complex numbers, such as $z$ here. Although $|z| \in \mathbb{R}$ and not $\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be okay?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife Because I was speculating that "square root would need to be defined for complex numbers".

Comment: In what context? $a^2+b^2$ is a non-negative real number, not just any complex number, so the real square root function is allowed to be applied to it.

Comment: Consider $k = |z|$. As $k^2$ is real and positive, it makes sense to calculate $\sqrt {|z|^2} $.

Comment: The wording is weird. I'm guess you are really asking why you can take the square root when defining $|z|$?

Comment: No, I'm asking what @JnxF answered.

Comment: @mavavilj Then you would have problems with $\sqrt{1}$ as well as $1$ is a complex number. You have to consider why it would become illegal all the suddenly just because you've taken a detour into complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you write $z=a+bi$, this usually implicitly means "with $a,b$ real numbers."

There are lots of ways to write any complex number as $a+bi$ if you allow $a,b$ to take values in $\mathbb C$, but there is always exactly one way to write $z=a+bi$ with $a,b$ real.

So if we define a function on $z$, such as $|z|$, in terms of $z=a+bi$, it is implied that $a,b$ in $\mathbb R$. Then $a^2+b^2$ is always a non-negative real number, so we can take the square root.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that one assumes known roots of non-negative **real** numbers. The square-root there means the non-negative real root of a non-negative real number.

The quantity $a^2 +b^2 = |z|^2$ is non-negative real.